# Eben und halt, was ist der Unterschied?

Tags: word-choice, modal-particle

Im Sinne von "just", wenn es einen Unterschied gibt. Are there situations or connotations particular to either?

Comment: Kannst Du Beispielsätze nennen? "Eben" und "Halt" haben viele verschiedene Bedeutungen, die hier wohl nicht gemeint sind.

Comment: @pmf natürlich. I asked prematurely so I don't forget the question. I will add an examples when I get home.

Comment: Purely regional difference - just like "eben" vs. the annoying "ebent", which is simply wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you're talking about the use of this words for justification or declaring in a sentence: "Das ist halt so" - "Das ist eben so"
In this particular use, there is no difference. I think "eben" would be the more correct form, while "halt" is more slang.
If you mean something else, I'm sorry for my assumption.

EDIT: it can also be replaced by several other words, or even used in combination: "einfach", "nunmal" or to combine it if you really want to point out that this IS this way: "Das ist nunmal halt einfach so."
cheers.

Comment: Wie kann ein Wort “the more correct form“ eines anderen sein? Zudem ist _halt_ kein Slang.

Comment: Da würde ich jetzt einfach mal "Sprachform" als Argument anführen. "Eben" ist im Schriftdeutsch und in formalen Unterredungen weitaus gängiger als "halt".
Und doch, es ist umgangsprachlich. Der komplette Satz ist es. Mittlerweile ist es zwar stark in den trivialen Sprachgebrauch eingebunden, jedoch als Ausdruck etwas aus dem "gesprochenen deutsch"

Comment: Offenbar setzen Sie _Gängigkeit im formalen Kontext_ fälschlicherweise mit _Korrektheit_ und _Umgangssprache_ mit _Slang_ gleich. Das sind jeweils verschiedene Konzepte. Was Sie im Kommentar dazu geschrieben haben, ist durchaus richtig, was in Ihrer Antwort steht, nicht.

Comment: Ich denke, da ist mein englisch einfach nicht ausgereift genug für die korrekte Formulierung. Sie können meinen Beitrag jedoch gern editieren, zum Wohle aller.

Answer (score 0):

Both are equally valid, though there may be regional preferences, which I do not know.

For me, it is a matter of rhythm and style which one to use. Compare, for example,

> Das ist *halt* so.
>   
>   Das ist *eben* so.

The first sentence contains four one-syllable words and therefore sounds better than the second sentence, the rhythm of which is broken by the two-syllable word *eben*.

Now compare

> Das ist *eben* deine Sache.
>   
>   Das ist *halt* deine Sache.

Here, the sentence sounds better with *eben*.